# What are possible ways to hack a telepathic transmission or communication?

Tags: science-fiction, telepathy

According to [this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telepathy) dictionary, *Telepathy means a way of communicating thoughts directly from one person's mind to another person's mind **without using words or signals***

If we consider this definition then there is no existence of any signal out there which has our modulated thought that can be demodulated illegally or hacked.

Therefore, what can be the ways to hack (not interrupt) telepathic conversations without any signal altogether?

Comment: I think this definition means "signals" as in motioning with your hands or nodding up and down; if you interpret it as "no radio waves" etc then it is impossible to communicate telepathically short of quantum shenanigans, which really don't sound too comfortable to work out

Comment: By "hack", do you mean "eavesdrop" or "listen in on"? Or do you mean "edit" or "alter"?

Comment: To be completely honest with you, the question cannot be answered without first stating the mechanisms through which telepathy occurs. Since telepathy is something not proven by science, there are many different ways to envision it transpiring. Do you want us to just make up something that sounds plausible? There already are so many different existing mystical philosophies about how it transpires.

Comment: You might find [Thought Forms by Annie Besant and C.W.Leadbeater](http://isisinvokes.com/index.php/en/free-pdf-s/send/23-annie-besant-and-c-w-leadbeater-books/90-thought-forms-1901-annie-besant-and-c-w-leadbeater) interesting--short, easy to read and informative. For a much greater in-depth analysis of thought in physical and non-physical realms, try [Thinking and Destiny by Howard Percival](http://selfdefinition.org/yoga/Harold%20Percival%20-%20Thinking%20and%20Destiny.pdf) very detailed, but quite long and extremely involved.

Comment: If you want to read the Thought Forms book, I can tell you what the descriptions of the colors in the front of the book say. Unfortunately, the scan is so low quality it's almost unreadable. Thankfully I've read a hard copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if by signals you mean no hand gestures or other predetermined signs then there could still be some kind of transmission passing between the two like a radio wave.
Then you might be able to develop some kind of psychic detector to intercept them.

If you mean nothing of any kind and the thoughts arrive directly via quantum teleportation or magic or something then you'll have to get the information from one of the participants. There are a couple options.

1. **Telepathy.** If you have two telepaths communicating mind to mind, then it may be possible for a third telepath to tap into the mind of one of the participants and read out the information after it arrives.
2. **Plant a bug.** You know, [some kind of implant or something](https://youtu.be/3i42Smtbmeg) that will read the brain waves of the host and relay them back to you somehow. It may be hard to do this without the subject noticing.
3. **Overt Subversion.** Get one of them working for you one way or another.
   [image] [image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered a (literal) [man in the middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack?

Presumably for two people to be able to communicate mind to mind there has to be some way of one person finding the other and 'locking on'. If this process could be subverted somehow (perhaps a very skilled psychic mimicking the though patterns of the intended recipient in a slightly 'louder' way), then the original messenger will literally pass the psychic message to the attacker, who is then free to peruse, modify, and eventually resend the message to the original recipient. Dependant upon the skill of the man in the middle this could be almost untraceable, blatantly obvious or act as total paranormal communications jamming.

If, of course, the psychic connection is created once in person and is then unbreakable this technique won't work, but it's worth considering.

Also raises a lot of potential for [PCM's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_countermeasure)